# When should SQL server connection be closed in a script?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, prepared-statement

If I have a redirect header  is it ok to close the connection to the server after it?
For example, what's the best order of the following commands:

- `header('Location: example.com');`
- `mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);`
- `mysqli_close($link);`

Should all these things be done as soon as possible or is it ok to put them at the end of the script?

EDIT: what is the point of `exit`? If the script naturally ends (with `?>`) is `exit` still nescecary?

Comment: Unless it is a persistent connection it will automatically be closed. The only thing you need after the `header` is `exit;` and please use a proper full URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd normally `exit` straight after redirecting, like this

```
header('Location: example.com');
exit;
```

so this will be near the end of your script.

The others should be placed after you've finished with the resources, and before you exit.  However, PHP should tidy up after you. If you don't explicitly close the statement or link, PHP will do it, so you probably don't need them at all.

Comment: Oops - didn't look at the content of the header! You'd normally `exit` after this: `header('Location: example.com');`

Comment: The header is towards the bottom of the script because data from the SQL server is used to set session variables which are used in the page redirected to. Wouldn't it be possible for the page redirected to to try and use a session variable before it was set if the redirect is done before the rest of the things on this page?

Comment: @Celeritas - you didn't post any code, so the context wasn't clear. You're right - I'll tweak the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to do them at all.

After `header('Location...` you should use `exit` immediately.  Open connections are closed when the script exits automatically.  You could manually close them and use `exit` after that, though.

You only need to worry about manually closing the connections if you're running out of connections during long-running scripts, but you may have other problems at that point.